In CreateView, django-bootstrap-modal-forms is executing the form twice
I'm pretty new to Django, and the English isn't my language. I'll try my best to explain what happens when I'm using django-bootstrap-modal-forms.
I have a page that has a button that calls a POPUP (a modal form). This form has objective adds a 'unit of measurement' in a table.
When the popup opens to user, he types the unit and click submit. But the process tries record twice same register. But not happen because of the my routine validation, that is in forms.py. therefore, only one record is write. The other record is showing in other page. This page is without format and with a message erro below of field 'unit of measure'. The message is 'Invalid: Unit already exists!'
I expected the process to save the record, close the popup window and display the message 'Unit has been added!' on the page that called the popup.
I use django-bootstrap-modal-forms version 3.0.4 with Django 4.2.9.
Please, has anyone experienced this? Managed to solve?
Below I show the codes to help you understand what I did.
unidades_list.html
{% extends 'base.html '%}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap5 %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10">
        <center><h1>Unidades</h1></center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 mt-2"> 
        <a class="cadastrar bs-modal btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-form-url="{% url 'unidade:unidade_create' %}">Adicionar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- display the filter -->
      {% crispy filter.form filter.form.helper %}
      <!-- display the table -->
      {% render_table table 'django_tables2/bootstrap5.html' %}
    </div> 
    <!-- Mensagens do processo --> 
    {% for message in messages %}
      {%  if message.tags == 'success' %}
        <script src = "https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var m = "{{ message }}";
            swal("Perfeito !", m, "success")
        </script>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>  
  
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block extrascripts %}
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () { 
    
    $(".cadastrar").each(function () {
      $(".cadastrar").modalForm({
        formURL: $(".cadastrar").data("form-url"), 
        modalID: "#modal", 
        errorClass:".is-invalid"
      });
    });

    $(".editar").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({
        formURL: $(this).data("form-url"), 
        modalID: "#modal", 
        errorClass:".is-invalid"
      });
    });

    $(".excluir").each(function () {
        $(this).modalForm({
          formURL: $(this).data("form-url"), 
          modalID: "#modal", 
          isDeleteForm: true
        });
    });   
  });
</script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}


urls.py
from django.urls import path
from apps.configuracoes.unidades.views import *

app_name = 'unidade'

urlpatterns = [
    path('unidades_list', Unidades_ListView.as_view(), name='unidades_list'),
    path('unidade_create', Unidade_BSModalCreateView.as_view(), name='unidade_create'),
]

forms.py
from django import forms 
from apps.configuracoes.unidades.models  import *

class Unidade_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = cadastro36_UnidadesdeMedidas
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ('created_on', 'created_by','updated_on','updated_by' )  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    # Validações de mais de um campo no formulário
    def clean(self):
         # Validar Unidade
        cleaned_data = super().clean()  
        unidade = cleaned_data.get('unidade')
        insert = self.instance.id == None
        unidade_existe =  cadastro36_UnidadesdeMedidas.objects.filter(unidade=unidade).exists()
        if insert:
            if unidade_existe: 
                self.add_error('unidade', 'Inválido: Unidade já existe!')
        return cleaned_data

views.py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin 
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView 
from apps.configuracoes.unidades.models import *
from apps.configuracoes.unidades.forms import *

class Unidade_BSModalCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   
    model = cadastro36_UnidadesdeMedidas
    form_class = Unidade_Form
    template_name = 'configuracoes/unidades/modal_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("unidade:unidades_list")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Unidade_BSModalCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['titulo'] = "Adicionar Unidades"
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        messages.success(self.request, "Unidade foi adicionada!")
        response = super().form_valid(form) 
        return response


